# add action for wordpress query at a specific position

Tags: wp-query, actions

I wanted to allow users to put custom code to placed in between the wordpress query.
say If I create a post query I want display an image in between--eg after 2nd, or after 5th post. is it possible to do with add action? so that with apply action code can be placed inbetween.

Comment: You can call `add_action()` or `apply_filters()` anwhere in your PHP/WordPress code. Just determine the proper position based on your specific requirements.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you, how can I be specific to a certain position in the query? any reference pls if possible

Comment: I've posted an answer. But I'm not very sure if that's what you meant. Let me know, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Yes, absolutely, it is possible.***

And here's an example: Use an action and pass the post's position in the loop to the action's callback/function, and let the callback run the conditional and display the image if applicable.

```php
$position = 1; // start at 1
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' );

    // Show custom image, if any.
    do_action( 'my_loop_custom_image_at_position', $position );

    $position++;
endwhile;
```

Callback: (yes, the conditional could be done in the above loop, but based on your question, I think this is what you're looking for?)

```php
add_action( 'my_loop_custom_image_at_position', function( $position ){
    if ( $position > 2 ) {
        echo '<img src="https://placeimg.com/728/90/any" />';
    } else { // optional 'else'
        echo 'Position is less than 2. So we don\'t show custom image.';
    }
} );
```

PS: In the callback, you can use `get_post()` to get the current post's data.

Comment: Thank you, The method is totally clear for me now :)

Comment: You're welcome! :)